# Vector combination and array sorting

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I have two column vector

```
A = [8, 2, 2, 1]
B = ['John', 'Peter', 'Paul', 'Evans']
```

How do I combine them to have an array of

```
C =

     8     'John'
     2     'Peter'
     2     'Paul'
     1     'Evans'
```

And how do I sort C in ascending order such that I have

```
C =

     1     'Evans'
     2     'Paul'
     2     'Peter'
     8     'John'
```

I just migrated to python from Matlab and I am having difficulty in this.

Comment: Are those NumPy arrays or lists?

Comment: @Divakar Those are NumPy arrays.

Comment: Where did `John` vanish? Why was `Paul` promoted up in the order? Is he like that Paul Ryan? :)

Comment: @Divakar Correction made. typo error :)

Comment: And whats with Paul's promotion? Any sorting criteria there?

Comment: i am sorting based on the A column @Divakar

Comment: Right, but Paul and Peter both have `2` in `A`. So, why was Paul put at second position above Peter?

Comment: Well there is no criteria, it could be Peter before Paul. I just intend sorting based on the A column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an approach using [`np.argsort`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html) with `kind = mergesort` that also maintains the order to get the sort ordered indices. So, we can stack the input arrays in columns and index with those indices for desired output, like so -

```
In [172]: A
Out[172]: array([8, 2, 2, 1])

In [173]: B
Out[173]: 
array(['John', 'Peter', 'Paul', 'Evans'], 
      dtype='|S5')

In [174]: sidx = A.argsort(kind='mergesort')

In [175]: np.column_stack((A,B))[sidx]
Out[175]: 
array([['1', 'Evans'],
       ['2', 'Peter'],
       ['2', 'Paul'],
       ['8', 'John']], 
      dtype='|S21')
```

---

If you would like to keep the `int` type for the first column in the output array, you could create an object dtype array, like so -

```
arr = np.empty((len(A),2),dtype=object)
arr[:,0] = A
arr[:,1] = B
out = arr[sidx] # sidx is same as from previous approach
```

Result -

```
In [189]: out
Out[189]: 
array([[1, 'Evans'],
       [2, 'Peter'],
       [2, 'Paul'],
       [8, 'John']], dtype=object)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `np.column_stack()` and `np.sort()`:

```
In [9]: np.column_stack((A, B))
Out[9]: 
array([['8', 'John'],
       ['2', 'Peter'],
       ['2', 'Paul'],
       ['1', 'Evans']], 
      dtype='<U5')

In [10]: 

In [10]: np.sort(np.column_stack((A, B)))[::-1]
Out[10]: 
array([['1', 'Evans'],
       ['2', 'Paul'],
       ['2', 'Peter'],
       ['8', 'John']], 
      dtype='<U5')
```

Comment: It seems not to be sorting well. It gives me [2,2,8,1] arrangement